# Why need setState func Inside useEffect func on this code

Tags: react-hooks

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

/** HeaderModal custom hooks */
const useHeaderModal = () => {
  const [modalOpened, setModalOpened] = useState(false)

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpened(true)
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpened(false)
  }

  interface IProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
  }

  const ModalPortal: React.FC<IProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const ref = useRef<Element | null>()
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      setMounted(true)
      if (document) {
        const dom = document.querySelector('#root-modal')
        ref.current = dom
      }
    }, [])

    if (ref.current && mounted && modalOpened) {
      return createPortal(
        <Container>
          <div
            className="modal-background"
            role="presentation"
            onClick={closeModal}
          ></div>
          {children}
        </Container>,
        ref.current,
      )
    }
    return null
  }

  return {
    openModal,
    closeModal,
    ModalPortal,
  }
}

export default useHeaderModal
```

This code is custom hook for opening modal.
And I don't understand 'Why need setState func Inside useEffect func on this code?'.

When I eliminate
`setMounted(true)`, ref was not created.

And then in case clicking modal open button
ref was not much created.

When the button is pressed only when the setMounted function
is put in useEffect
The ref is created and then the modal is opened.

Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for calling `setMounted(true)` is to indicate that the component is mounted. The callback function in `useEffect` is called after the component is first rendered, so calling `setMounted(true)` at this point will indicate "this component is mounted."